# How to find factor algebra in Lie algebra.

Tags: lie-algebras

For Lie algebra of 9 elements $e1\dots e9$, the commutation relations are defined as:

$[{\it e1},{\it e4}]=-{\it e4},[{\it e1},{\it e6}]=-{\it e6},[{\it e1}
,{\it e7}]=-{\it e7},[{\it e1},{\it e8}]=-{\it e8},[{\it e2},{\it e3}]
={\it e5},[{\it e2},{\it e4}]={\it e6},[{\it e2},{\it e5}]=-{\it e3},[
{\it e2},{\it e6}]=-{\it e4},[{\it e3},{\it e4}]={\it e7},[{\it e3},{
\it e5}]={\it e2},[{\it e3},{\it e7}]=-{\it e4},[{\it e5},{\it e6}]={
\it e7},[{\it e5},{\it e7}]=-{\it e6}
$

For $S = \langle a_{3}e2+\frac{a_{3}^{2}}{a_{2}}e3+e7,a_{2}e2+a_{3}e3+e6,e8,e9\rangle$

$N = \langle a_{2}e2+a_{3}e3+e6+a_{8}e8+a_{9}e9\rangle$.

**How I can find factor algebra $S/N$ ?**

Comment: @DavidTowers: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is a little confusing, as you've used square brackets for the Lie product and in the definition of S and N. In the latter I assume the square brackets stand for the subspace spanned by the elements within the brackets. In which case, S is 4-dimensional and N is 1-dimensional, so S/N is 3-dimensional. If we denote the basis vectors of S by x1, x2, x3 and x4 for simplicity, then S/N is spanned by x1+N, x2+N, x3+N and x4+N. Note that x2+N, x3+N and x_4+N are linearly dependent, so a basis for S/N is, for example, x1+N, e8+N and e9+N. The products are easy to compute

Comment: Can you please give further details as I am very immature in linear algebra. Please provide complete basis of $S/N$ if you can.

Comment: Have you taken $x_{1} = a_{3}e2+\frac{a_{3}^{2}}{a_{2}}e3+e7,x_{2} = a_{2}e2+a_{3}e3+e6, x_{3} = e8, x_{4} = e9$ ?

Comment: Yes I have. So the basis for S/N is a_{3}e2+\frac{a_{3}^{2}}{a_{2}}e3+e7 + N, e8 + N, e9 + N. The products are all zero, so S/N is the abelian Lie algebra of dimension 3.